# Webpack library build returns undefined when imported

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-splitchunks

Just sharing a problem and solution I spent hours on debugging:

I have a codebase that I want to build as a library with webpack, and include in another project. However, when I import the output file in the other library, it returns `undefined`.

This is the (simplified) webpack config:

```js
{
  entry: './index.js',
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'app/my-app.[name].js'
    library: 'my-app',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      cacheGroups: {
        vendors: {
          name: 'vendors',
          test: /[\\/](node_modules|libraries)[\\/]/
        }
      }
    },
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
      cache: true,
      sourceMap: true,
      parallel: true,
      exclude: [/my-app.vendors.js/]
    })]
  },
}
```

From the other project, I would import the library as follows:

```js
const lib = require('./lib/my-app/dist/my-app.main');
console.log(lib);
```

Without any errors on the page, the console would simply show `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the solution was simple: since I'm using `splitChunks`, the output consists of 3 files: `my-app.runtime.js`, `my-app.vendors.js` and `my-app.main.js`. I assumed each chunk would `require` its necessary dependencies automatically, but I assumed wrong. To make the library work, I needed to import like this:

```js
require('./lib/my-app/dist/my-app.runtime');
require('./lib/my-app/dist/my-app.vendors');
const lib = require('./lib/my-app/dist/my-app.main');
console.log(lib);
```

The other is important, since `main` will need `vendors` and `runtime`.

Quite obvious if you think about it, but maybe this will help someone else who happens to miss it. The lack of errors in the console does not help the debugging.